# My flash player not autoplaying in Chrome version 45

Tags: google-chrome

With Chrome version 45, "Chrome Now Automatically Pauses Flash Content That Isn’t ‘Central’ To A Web Page". 
How does chrome determine 'Central' content?

On my web page there is only one player on top left. This is flash based. The business requirement is to auto play the content whenever the page loads but it seems chrome latest version does not allow to autoplay the content and instead displays a Play icon on it. How does Chrome determines Central content? I tried to put the focus on the player but still it does not autoplay.

Is there a way we can overwrite chrome setting through UI to "Run all plugin content" under content settings?
Is there any other alternative that i can try. Any inputs will be appreciated.

Thank You!

Regards,
Hakim

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got the solution for my issue. 
Chrome requires minimum height, width, aspect ratio for it to consider the player as central/important content of the page. In my case the height of the player was 267px and for chrome the min needed is 298 (see below link). I changed it to 298px and it worked :)
Please see below link/code if you need more details:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch/#chromium/src/content/renderer/peripheral_content_heuristic.cc